# I need a regular expression to get the country code of an URL

Tags: php, regex, url

I am in need of a regular expression to get the extension of a URL such as the country code...

For example I have 3 sites that have different domain extensions for three countries as follows.

```
http://www.domain.com
domain.de/
domain.co.uk
```

I need a regular expression that gets the url extension in the above strings. returning either "com", "de", or "uk"

Keep in mind that the domain might be a different string with trailing slashes or without.

So the perfect regex would be able to pull de out of the following stings:

```
"domain.de" or "http://www.domain.de" or "www.domain.de/"
```

The closest I have come is by using the following:

```
\w*$
```

but alas this doesn't work with a trailing slash.

Comment: You want .com, .de or .co.uk OR only .com, .co or .uk ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need that regex work only on examples you've added it can be really easy:

```
\.([a-z]{2,3})\/?$
```

this will take the country from all type of inputs you've given us:

```
http://www.domain.com
domain.de
http://www.domain.de
www.domain.de/
```

the country code is in capture group 1.

Answer (score 2):

Restricting to HTTP and HTTPS, you might use:

```
/^(https?:\/\/)?([^@\/]+@)?[a-z0-9.]+\.([a-z]{2,4})(:[0-9]+)?\/?$/
                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You'll find the TLD in $3.

```
$ php -r '$t="example.ca"; preg_match("/^(https?:\/\/)?([^@\/]+@)?[a-z0-9.]+\.([a-z]{2,4})(:[0-9]+)?\/?$/", $t, $m); print $m[3]."\n";'
ca
$ php -r '$t="http://user:password@www.example.ca/"; preg_match("/^(https?:\/\/)?([^@\/]+@)?[a-z0-9.]+\.([a-z]{2,4})(:[0-9]+)?\/?$/", $t, $m); print $m[3]."\n";'
ca
```

Comment: I'd avoid doing this much URL parsing yourself. Maybe use [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to get the domain name, then do your regex starting there.

Answer (score 0):

Using what you already have, we can adjust it easily to take account for the trailing slash

```
\w*[/]?$
```